# How to pass a row variable to another page?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $flag=0;
        $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sconnect');
        $location = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
        $data="SELECT * FROM events WHERE location='$location';";
        $resmy=mysqli_query($con,$data);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resmy)) { 
            $gid = $row['event_id'];
            $gquery ="select * from events where event_id='$gid';";
            $myresq = mysqli_query($con,$gquery);
            $grow = mysqli_fetch_array($myresq);
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['event_id']."</td><td>".$grow['gname']." 
            </td><td>".$grow['location']."</td><td>".$grow['date_from']." 
            </td><td>".$grow['date_to']."</td><td>".$grow['venue_details']." 
            </td><td>".$grow['participants']."</td>
            <td><form action='joineventphp.php' method='POST'><input 
            type='hidden' name='event_id' value='$row['event_id']'/><input 
            type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' /></form></td> 
            </tr>";
            $flag=1;
          }
           if(!$flag)
             {
                 echo "<tr><td>No events</td><td>found.</td></tr>";
             }
    }
?>
```

I wish to send "$row['event_id']" variable to another page once I click on register. Later in the page joineventphp.php I wish to store it in database. How to do this ?

Comment: try `<input 
            type='hidden' name='event_id' value='{$row['event_id']}'/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input type='hidden' name='event_id' value='$row['event_id']'/>
```

Do

```
<input type='hidden' name='event_id' value='{$row['event_id']}'/>
```

likely you have a syntax or parse error in there for example (we have to agree on this first)

```
 //this is a very simplified version of what you are doing
 //you have a double quoted string your putting an array access variable into
 //I have the same thing, agree?
 $foo = ['a' => 'b'];
 echo "some $foo['a'] thing";
```

Output

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1df3ff50cba4b246b9f57be78f9fb8962f2633a)

When you do this:

```
    echo "some {$foo['a']} thing";
    //or
    echo "some ".$foo['a']." thing";
```

That goes away and everything works as expected.  PHP only interpolates simple variables like this `$var` so both the above ways let PHP know that everything inside "this thing" is a variable.

It should be more clear when you look how you did it before this part:

```
  <td>".$row['event_id']."</td>
```

Which is one of the two ways I mentioned above, you just missed this one.